# using for loop to pass values in DATAROW

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I've defined a method for UserLogin. Here I am passing values to DATAROW. 
Here is the code:

```
public class ApplicationUser
    {        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string UserRole { get; set; }            
        public DateTime DateOfRegister { get; set; }

        public bool UserLogin(string Username, string Password)
        {            
            string strQuery = string.Format("select Username, Password from ApplicationUser where Username = '{0}' and Password = '{0}'", Username, Password);            
            DataTable dt = helper.ExecuteDataSet(strQuery).Tables[0];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow ro = dt.Rows[0];
                this.Id = ro.Field<int>("Id");
                this.Username = ro.Field<string>("Username");
                this.Password = ro.Field<string>("Password");                   
                this.UserRole = ro.Field<string>("UserRole");
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;

        }
    }
```

How can I do the below operation using **FOR loop**, is it  possible or not?

```
DataRow ro = dt.Rows[0];    
    this.Id = ro.Field<int>("Id");
    this.Username = ro.Field<string>("Username");
    this.Password = ro.Field<string>("Password");       
    this.UserRole = ro.Field<string>("UserRole");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare  below code under one entity

```
   public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string UserRole { get; set; }            
    public DateTime DateOfRegister { get; set; }
```

Then in your class make list or collection of entity and add to that list or collection for available rows.

```
List<Entity> lstEntity = new List<Entity>();
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
            foreach( Datarow r in dt.Rows){ 
                Entity e= new Entity();   
                e.Id = r.Field<int>("Id");
                e.Username = r.Field<string>("Username");
                e.Password = r.Field<string>("Password");                   
                e.UserRole = r.Field<string>("UserRole");
                lstEntity.Add(e);
               }
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: @ Amit! Thanks for your answer. I want to know what is the **advantage of using for loop in this scenario**. What is the best way for using DATA ROW? Can you please explain me.

Comment: It depends on your scenario. If you want all returned rows from query for further processing or pass to UI , which is general way, You will accumulate all your data, like above ,by using loop in business entity or entity which UI knows. As per your query it will always return one row as user information with respect to userid will be unique. So just using datarow[0] will be enough. But when you expect more than one row, in those scenario you need loop or or other method of data population.

Comment: Consider SQL query is only select Username, Password from ApplicationUser. In this case you will get multiple records and if you want all user information to datagrid then either you will bind datatable which is returned to the grid or you will populate your own collection and bind to grid. And looping is one of the way you can make collection.